# What does "unified infrastructure" mean, and how is it different in 2010 than in 2007?

Tags: comparison

I'm preparing for a client presentation, and all the Microsoft literature about SharePoint 2010 boasts of "cutting costs with unified infrastructure."  However, I have been able to find no detail which might explain what that phrase means.

Does anyone know what "unified infrastructure" is supposed to mean, and what the difference between SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2007/WSS 3.0 is in that regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a topic that comes up in a lot of my high level business value pitches.  Essentially most medium to large companies have a lot of different systems and applications that are all on different platforms.  In many cases they span different technologies as well as different servers.  There is a cost to maintaining the servers as well as the applications in addition to end user training costs to train them on multiple different systems.

SharePoint offers a unified platform that can be used to consolidate these platforms to a single unified platform.

In addition there is also a stronger push now to use a single farm to extend to support extranet and public facing Internet scenarios.  This is absolutely possible, but there are security, licensing, and scalability requirements that need to be considered.

The big difference between 2007 and 2010 is just greater integration capabilities and the service application model.  The service Application Model supports different scenarios such as greater flexibility in deciding which services run on which server, and also connecting services between farms.

Comment: +1 The idea is any server in the farm can run any service is generally what this means. There are a few exceptions (eg. user profile synchronization for a UPA can run on only a single server at a time).